# AWS Skills Development for Echo Dot for Beginners

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I was looking for a feature that makes my echo dot to say the time in 24 hour clock. But I dont think the folks at Amazon haven't thought everything through. AM/PM is just annoying. So I thought why not make it myself and try it out on my echo dot. Coz requesting the feature through the app and asking for it on the forums didn't help much. At least this way, I will get to learn something new in the process.

But here's the thing, I have never worked on AWS or any Amazon related development. So I have virtually zero idea of where to start. All I know is that if it remotely comes close to JAVA, i think I should be able to make it work!

So I had a few question about my mission! :)

1. Is it doable? From the point, that, would it be some copyright violation or something?
2. I went on to the AWS website and started looking for some guides, do I have 
   pay for use of their service for the dev work?
3. And I found that there are a few kits mentioned on the site like "alexa-skill-kit-sdk" and "alexa voice skill" or something similar, for this would I need both or just the voice part.
4. Where can I get some voice samples? Or to make it work, I have to record my voice with all the combinations of the time?

Since I am just starting at this, I dont have much idea about where to start.

Comment: You're really over-complicating this. Haven't you noticed that all Alexa skills use the same voice? You don't upload audio files to create an Alexa skill, you just give it some code that generates text, and the Alexa service converts the text to speech for you. There are so many tutorials out there for getting started building an Alexa skill. I suggest you start looking at those instead of asking for someone to guide you through the process here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some answers for you, first no programming is required to provide 24 hour (military) time declaration from your Alexa device if you ask your device, Alexa, " What is the time in Military time?"  She will give you time in 24 time format. 
Secondly to program a custom skill you could follow this perfect for beginner chart https://developer.amazon.com/alexa-skills-kit/alexa-skill-python-tutorial . 
There are also non programmed ways to make an application using blueprints https://blueprints.amazon.com/ .
Lastly utilizing AWS ask-cli you can create a fully functional 'hello-world' application simply by typing ask new then ask deploy in your terminal https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smapi/quick-start-alexa-skills-kit-command-line-interface.html.

Comment: Yes, I know about asking for the military time. But I want the 24 hour time, when i ask for just the time. Also setting reminders is also an issue. Also it doesn't understand 24 hour clock as well. If I say, Fifteen Hundred Hours. It just doesn't understand. Unless I say 3PM. It wont register a reminder. Kinda weird.
But thanks for the link. I would go over them and see where i end up!